# No simple group of order $858$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If G is simple then one of the index must be 1. I've tried that route, but I couldn't go anywhere for example for $n_7$ it has the following possibilities $n_7 = 1$ or $n_7 = 5$.

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean $858$, then you shouldn't be having this problem, since $7$ does not divide $858$.

Assuming that $858$ is wrong and the rest is correct, you shouldn't have any trouble eliminating "$n_7=5$" because $5$ is not $1 \pmod 7$, which is what one Sylow theorem asserts.

Since $858=2•3•11•13$, you can get down to the cases where $n_{13}=66$ and $n_{11}=78$. But that would mean at least $780$ elements of order $11$ and at least $792$ elements of order $13$, but you can't have both at the same time. So there must be a normal $11$-subgroup or a normal $13$-subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that if $G$ is a group of order $2n$, where $n$ is an odd integer, then $G$ is not simple because $G$ has a normal subgroup of index $2$.